# Prestashop webservice: after adding the products are invisible

Tags: web-services, prestashop

Prestashop webservice: after adding the products are invisible and I should resave the product from the back office.

My code is:

```
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api?schema=synopsis'));
                            $product = $xml->children()->children();
                            $product->price = str_replace(',','.',$p['price']);
                            $product->wholesale_price = str_replace(',','.',$p['price']);
                            $product->active = '1'; 
                            $product->advanced_stock_management = '0';
                            $product->on_sale = 1;
                            $product->show_price = 1;
                            $product->available_for_order = 1;
                            $product->name->language[0][0] = $p['name'];
                            $product->name->language[0][0]['id'] = 1;
                            $product->name->language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . 1;
                            $product->description->language[0][0] = !empty($p['desc']) ? substr($p['desc'], 0, 21844) : ' ';
                            $product->description->language[0][0]['id'] = 1;
                            $product->description->language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . 1;
                            $product->description_short->language[0][0] = !empty($p['short_desc']) ? substr($p['short_desc'], 0 , 100) : ' ';
                            $product->description_short->language[0][0]['id'] = 1;
                            $product->description_short->language[0][0]['xlink:href'] = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/languages/' . 1;
                            $product->reference = !empty($p['refcode']) ? $p['refcode'] : ' ';
                            $product->ean13 = !empty($p['ean']) ? $p['ean'] : ' ';
                            $product->weight = !empty($p['weight']) ? $p['weight'] : ' ';
                            $product->depends_on_stock = 0;
                            $product->state = 1;
                            $product->redirect_type = '301-category';
                            $category_id = $c->id;
                            $product->id_category_default = $category_id;
                            $opt = array('resource' => 'products');
                            $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
                            $xml = $webService->add($opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue

See => https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/28586

There are some workaround and suggestions that might help you.